# Suppose $\varphi \colon [0,1] \to \Bbb R$ is three times continuously differentiable function

Tags: numerical-methods

I was looking at old exam papers and was stuck on the following problem:

> Suppose $\,\,\varphi \colon [0,1] \to \Bbb R$  is three times
>   continuously differentiable function. Suppose further  that
>   the iterates defined by $x_{n+1}=\varphi(x_n), n \ge 0$
>   converge to the fixed point $\xi$ of $\varphi$ . If the
>   order of convergence is three then which of the following options is  *correct*?
>
> 1. $\varphi'(\xi)=0,\,\,\varphi''(\xi)=0$
> 2. $\varphi'(\xi) \ne 0,\,\,\varphi''(\xi)=0$
> 3. $\varphi'(\xi)=0,\,\,\varphi''(\xi)\ne0$
> 4. $\varphi'(\xi)\ne 0,\,\,\varphi''(\xi)\ne 0$

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: I vote for option 1. Start with the Taylor polynomial of degree $2$ or $3$ at $\xi$ and the definition of order of convergence. It makes notation a bit easier to assume $\xi=0$.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have $\varphi(x)-\xi=O((x-\xi)^3)$, one needs the Taylor expansion of $\varphi$ at $\xi$ to be of the form $\xi+0(x-\xi)+0(x-\xi)^2+\dots$. Hence, 1) is correct